# Realm: setting NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey for realm file

Tags: ios, swift, realm, nsurl

I want to set the NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey for my realm file. The reason why is because I want to exclude it from iCloud. I have the following code:

```
public class func configure() {
    var config = Realm.Configuration()

    config.fileURL = config.fileURL!.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent?
        .URLByAppendingPathComponent("Test.realm")

    do {
        try config.fileURL?.setResourceValue(true, forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey)

    }
    catch {
        print("Failed to set backupkey")
    }

    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
}
```

However the function always fails to set the key. I see no issue at all since it's a simple do/catch. Any reasoning on why this wont work?

Comment: Does the file exist at that point? Can you catch the error and see what it says?

Comment: Error: The file "Test.realm" doesn't exist. How is this possible, is the realm only created after querying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code as written does not work as you can only apply the `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` attribute to a file that already exists, and the Realm files are not created until the Realm is first opened. You can address this in a few different ways:

1. Wait until after you've opened the Realm, then apply the attribute to Realm's files. Keep in mind that there are a few auxiliary files alongside the main Realm file that you'd likely also want to exclude.
2. Create a subdirectory to contain your Realm, and apply the attribute to the directory so that it and its contents are excluded. This can be done prior to opening the Realm, and will take care of the auxiliary files as well.
3. Store your Realm somewhere other than the Documents directory. If the Realm doesn't contain user data, which I assume is the case if you're willing to not back it up, then perhaps the Caches directory would be a more appropriate home for it. The contents of the Caches directory are already excluded from user's backups.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. I was always wondering when the Realm was  created, but this clears everything up. Clear answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your Realm database file has not been created yet. I think it is created either after you instantiate `Realm()` or after you `write` to the Realm DB. Once the file exists you can exclude it from backups.

Comment: An alternative approach could be to move the Realm's location to a directory of your own creation, and to mark the directory as excluded from backup. This would allow you to take care of this exclusion prior to opening the Realm.

Comment: @bdash I like this way better, you should turn this into an answer.